# Trouble with solidity: Can't deploy the project by hardhat!

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I'm trying to deploy a project by hardhat but this is my issue:

**HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: error code: 1020**

### This is my hardhat.config.js:

[image]

Comment: can you add more info. What command did you try to run?  Also, be sure to check that mumbai is up, they're nodes can be a bit spotty

Comment: This is my command: npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network matic

Comment: My metamask have been added and having some matic tokens